# Get the value of the index-column of a dataframe from the last row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the value of the index-column in the last row of a dataframe.
How can i get a value and not a series ?

Comment: What do you mean by `index-column`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need indexing - last value  of index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':[4,5,6,8,2,1],
         'B':list('qwerty')
}, index=list('abcdef'))

print (df)
   A  B
a  4  q
b  5  w
c  6  e
d  8  r
e  2  t
f  1  y

val = df.index[-1]
print (val)
f
```